# Como aplicar um efeito de "blur" quando um StageModal sobrepor um Stage já aberto em JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

Bem minha duvida é a seguinte, gostaria de aplicar um efeito no qual, quando eu abrir uma nova janela, a janela que ficou sobreposta fique desfocada tentei utilizar

```
public Stage stageModal(String controller, String titulo){
    try {
        AnchorPane root = new AnchorPane();
        root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/com/ProcessosJuridicos/view/"+controller+".fxml"));
        root.setStyle("-fx-background-color: black");
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        final Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle(titulo);
        GaussianBlur blur = new GaussianBlur(55);
        ColorAdjust adj = new ColorAdjust(0, -0.9, -0.5, 0);
        adj.setInput(blur);
        root.setEffect(adj);
        stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        stage.show();
        return stage;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

da forma que eu tentei fazer ele aplica o "efeito" na janela na qual foi aberta

Answer (score 0):

Tenta dessa forma, pois acredito que você deva pegar o owner do stage aberto como modal e aplicar o efeito;

```
GaussianBlur blur = new GaussianBlur(55);
final Stage stage = new Stage();
stage.getOwner().getScene().getRoot().setEffect(blur);
```

Pra você remover o efeito da janela pai quando o modal for fechado:

```
stage.setOnCloseRequest(event ->
   stage.getOwner().getScene().getRoot().setEffect(null)
);
```